# Which port did Alexander board his ship from, while returning from the Indian campaign?

Tags: alexander-the-great, ancient-india, greco-persian-wars

When Alexander was forced by his army to abandon the Indian campaign and to turn back, he took the sea route, whereas he ordered the army to cross the Gedrosian desert. Which ancient (and/or modern) port did he leave from? Cursory research doesn't reveal anything.

Comment: The sources I looked at have Alexander *with* the men in the Gedrosian. What source are you using?

Comment: Okay, I was wrong. Alexander did cross the desert along with his army.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alexander crossed the Gedrosian desert, with the main body of his army.

The fleet you have in mind is the fleet raised by [Nearchus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearchus) to explore the Persian Gulf. According to [Arrian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrian) (Anabasis, Book 6), the fleet sailed from the city of Patala, somewhere at the head of the Indus delta.